# Stuck at Haskell's module's output

Tags: haskell, module, io

I am making programming code which generates block diagrams. I'm trying to split my code into modules (functions). First module generates block diagrams. Other module asks to input names of the blocks and saves it as a strings(lines), but it doesn't let to export those strings to other modules (I would like to to export those strings as a variables and use in other module as a names of blocks). What could be a problem? Maybe somebody already found the same problem and have the solution? Thank You in advance!
Input.hs code :

```
   module Input (firstName, secondName, thirdName, fourthName) where 

   import Data.Char 

   main = do  
      putStrLn "Iveskite pirmo bloko pavadinima"  
      firstName <- getLine  
      putStrLn "Iveskite antro bloko pavadinima"  
      secondName <- getLine 
      putStrLn "Iveskite trecio bloko pavadinima"  
      thirdName <- getLine 
      putStrLn "Iveskite ketvirto bloko pavadinima"  
      fourthName <- getLine
```

Comment: You can't toplevel variables in Haskell can't depend on some IO running during the program

Answer (score 5):

When you export names from a module with `module Input (firstName, secondName, thirdName, fourthName) where`, those names have to be defined at top level, and therefore must be statically bound.  You instead could do something like

```
module Input (getNames) where

import Data.Char

getNames :: IO (String, String, String, String)
getNames = do
    putStrLn "Iveskite pirmo bloko pavadinima"  
    firstName <- getLine  
    putStrLn "Iveskite antro bloko pavadinima"  
    secondName <- getLine 
    putStrLn "Iveskite trecio bloko pavadinima"  
    thirdName <- getLine 
    putStrLn "Iveskite ketvirto bloko pavadinima"  
    fourthName <- getLine
    return (firstName, secondName, thirdName, fourthName)
```

Then from another file you could have

```
module Other where

import Input

doSomething :: IO ()
doSomething = do
    (n1, n2, n3, n4) <- getNames
    putStr "You entered:"
    putStr $ " " ++ n1
    putStr $ " " ++ n2
    putStr $ " " ++ n3
    putStr $ " " ++ n4
    putStrLn ""
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
module Input (firstName, secondName, thirdName, fourthName) where
```

means that your source file will define `firstName`, `secondName` etc. at the *top* level.

You have a definition of `firstName`, but it is defined inside the function `main` and cannot be seen out side of it.